# Getting the file name without extension in a Windows Batch Script

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file

I'm trying to create a right-click context menu command for compressing JavaScript files with YUI compressor. My ultimate goal is to try to get this to run on a context menu:

```
java.exe -jar yuicompressor-2.4.2.jar -o <filename>.min.js <filename>.js
```

I know I can use the variable `%1` to reference the file name being opened. I can't figure out how to get this command into a batch file syntax and haven't been able to find any answers online.

**Update:**
Jeremy's answer (+comments) worked. For anyone who stumbles upon this, here is what I had to do:

In the action I created for the JavaScript file, I used this as the command:

```
minify.bat "%1"
```

Which calls my batch script, which looks like this:

```
java.exe -jar yuicompressor-2.4.2.jar -o "%~dpn1.min.js" %1
```

For the batch script, keep in mind that the code above assumes the directories for java.exe & yuicompressor are both added to your `PATH` variables. If you don't add these to your path, you'll have to use the full path for the files.

The sequence `%~dpn` is used to get:

1. `%~d` - The drive
2. `%~p` - The path
3. `%~n` - The file name

Comment: See `CALL /?` for the full list of enhancements to windows batch parameters, including `%~x1` for the extension.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Change the action to call a batch file:

```
RunCompressor.bat "%1"
```

Use `%~n1` to get the filename without the extension in RunCompressor.bat:

```
start javaw.exe -jar yuicompressor-2.4.2.jar -o "%~n1.min.js" "%1"
```

[Helpful article](http://windowsitpro.com/article/articleid/13443/how-do-i-pass-parameters-to-a-batch-file.html)

start javaw.exe closes the command window when running the batch file.

Comment: I tried using that, and instead of it evaluating to the name of the file, I ended up with a file with a name of "`%~n1.min.js`".

Comment: What version of Windows are you using?

Comment: Oh, is that command line what you're entering into the File Types dialog as a new action?

Comment: I'm using the Folder Options settings to add the new action, like this: http://imgur.com/y5nuF

Comment: OK.  Use `%1` there, but call a `.bat` or `.vbs` file.  I've updated my answer.

Comment: How to get the file extension only ??

Answer (score 12):

```
echo path of this file name is: %~dp0
echo file name of this file without extension is:%~n0
echo file extention of this file is:%~x0
echo The file name of this file is: %~nx0
```

Answer (score 0):

Write your own class that determines the output filename to send to YUI compressor.

```
java.exe -cp yuicompressor-2.4.2.jar MyClass "%1"
```